# MVC 6 error handler not showing view page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Does anyone know why the Error.cshtml does not show up when exception error was triggered.  It showed a blank with HttpStatus 500 verbiage in web-browser's title.

```
//Startup...
public class Startup
{
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   {
       app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

       app.UseMvc(routes => {
           routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=SignIn}/{action=Index}");
       });
   }
}
//Controller...
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
public class SignInController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        throw new Exception("Testing error handling");
        return View();
    }
}
```

[Edited]
But if I use `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error.html");` then it will work because it's a static page.

Comment: Removing the Exception does show the page?

Comment: Yes, it would show the `/Signin/Index` View page.

Comment: This is strange your server actually serve a static file since there is no `app.UseStaticFiles();` in your `Configure` method. It's important to add it **after** `app.UseExceptionHandler("/error.html");`. But with /Home/Error I don't see why it doesn't work for you, I've tried the exact code as yours and it works great. Try to create a new ASP.NET 5 project using the `Web Application` template and check all the differences with your actual project.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parentheses in your route definition:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=SignIn}/{action=Index}");
```

Comment: It was a typo when I typed up this StackOverflow posting.  Fixed the typo now.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Since you see the HTTPStatus 500 verbiage on the title, the 500 page is loading, however, none of the css/js files are being loaded. Can you add `app.UseStaticFiles();` to `Configure()`?